# Envelope detector circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis

Why do these circuits have different output signals, please explain in detail. And how does the envelope detector work?[image]

Comment: They have different output signals because you gave them different input signals... Were you expecting some other result?

Comment: Can you post circuit diagrams instead of wiring diagrams?

Comment: Schematics, please.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgoVA2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a negative envelope peak detector.

If f is too high (100 kHz) then each cycle does not have enough time to charge up the negative peak , so it takes several cycles. Fig 1 looks like ~3 cycles to 64% peak of attack time or 30us must be around T1=30 us.

If f is too low ( 100 Hz) then the peak decays too much within each cycle of 10ms so the decay time T2 is approaching 10ms.

Both R values may be scaled down with C scaled up to get similar results.

Values are estimated quickly due to less than ideal photos.